# How do get a NSDictionary from the JSON string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsjsonserialization

I am getting response  from server and saving in NSString  like this

```
NSString *strValue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"str is %@",strValue);
```

----here is the strValue

```
"{\"Response\" : [{\"Responsecode\" : \"0\" , \"Response\" : \"Success\"}] , \"Data\" : [{\"ID\":1,\"DistributorID\":1,\"RoleID\":0,\"UserName\":\"admin\",\"Password\":\"LEDdWe3AXsJy+ECechi3fQ==\",\"Fname\":\"AHPrepaid.Ltd\",\"Lname\":\"\",\"EmailID\":\"info@ahprepaid.com\",\"MobileNumber\":\"9711679656\",\"IsActive\":true,\"ActiveFromDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1432105200000)\\\/\",\"ActiveToDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1440918000000)\\\/\",\"CreatedBy\":1,\"CreatedDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1432190029013)\\\/\",\"ModifiedBy\":1,\"ModifiedDtTm\":\"\\\/Date(1460112809167)\\\/\",\"ClientType\":1,\"Name\":\"Company\",\"Currency\":\"USD\",\"ClientTypeID\":1,\"CurrencyId\":1}]}"
```

now i want to get NSDictionary  from that nsstring (strValue)
i tried like this

```
 NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [strValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                             options:2                                                                  error:&jsonError];
```

NSLog(@"json is : %@",json);

but i am getting json is null . how to get the json object from the  strValue.

Comment: And what does `jsonError` tell you?  Also why `data` > `strValue` > `objectData`?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set this error

Comment: OK so the JSON message is corrupt.

Comment: what is solution for that . how can i get json

Comment: Give it uncorrupted JSON.

Comment: how to give that , i am getting data from server then i used NSString *strValue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; now i have json string in strValue . from that i am making json object NSData *data1 = [strValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsondistionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];